# How to connect fields in java?

Tags: java

In my project I ran into a situation that I could not quickly google.
I have several objects and write a value in the id field of each, when I change this id later, I need to update the value in the id fields of each object. Example `b = null; a = b; => a = null;`
after, for example, `b = 3`, it is necessary to update the value of `a = 3` without `a = b` again. I will try to explain in more detail.

```
class Student { private Long id; } 
class Class { private Long id; } 
Student s = new Student (); 
Class c = new Class (); 
c.getid = null; 
s.setId (c.getId); => s.getId == null;
```

after some operation `c.getId == 1;` but `s.getId == null` how i can do `s.getId == 1` without `s.setId (c.getId)`?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> b = 3, it is necessary to update the value of a = 3 without a = b
> again. Is this possible?

If fields `a` and `b` are of primitive data type then no. You would need to update both `a` and `b`.

If `a` and `b` are instance on an Object then yes, since `a` and `b` share the same memory reference. So if your fields are primitive data types you can wrap them inside a Custom Object with proper a set/get method and you are good to go.

If those fields can be read/write concurrently by multithreads you may need to also ensure mutual exclusion when accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, your question is in fact an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are barking up the wrong tree. The solution is not to change the Student's ID, but rather to pass references where they are needed. Here, I am suspecting that `id` represents the `id` of a class, and so the best solution is to give the Class class an `ArrayList<Student>` field (since it will hold multiple Students), and to give your Student an `ArrayList<Class>` field (since a Student can attend multiple classes).

Then, when a Student registers for a class (via some method), add that Class to its classes list, and add the Student to the Class's students list.

e.g.,

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // constructor, getters, setters
    
    public void addClass(Class class) {
        classes.add(class);
    }
    
    // also removeClass method, a getClasses method...
}
```

```
public class Class {
    private int id;
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // constructor, getters, setters
    
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }
    
    // also removeStudent method, a getStudents method...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your good explanation of question, but that would be better if you told us why. buy the way, I think this is a XY problem, the more important question is "why do you need this"?

let's speak about your question, there are few options that you should consider.

1. type of `a` and `b` is primitive
   since primitives have their own memory (not pointing to somewhere else), like C language, after the assignment nothing connects `a` and `b` and they can (and will) change separately.
   for example

```java
int a, b;
a = 3;
b = a;

a = 5;
// b is still 3
```

2. `a` and `b` are references and you want them to point to same object.
   Objects are in the heap and since there is no assignment overload (like [we have in cpp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/assignment_operators_overloading.htm)), after the assignment `a` and `b` are pointing to exact same object so each change in the object that a is pointing to, will seen from b. BUT REMEMBER this connection is unless a and b is pointing to same object and manipulate object state with `.`;

```java
class Student {
    int id;
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student a, b;
        a = new Student();
        a.id = 3;

        b = a;
        // they are now pointing to same object
        a.id = 5;
        // b.id is 5 too, basically same int

        b = null;
        // now they are disconnect
        // or maybe this: b = new Student()

    }
}
```

I think this could help and answer your question, but let's discuss about your code snippet too.

3. if you want references themselves change. for example:

```java
String a, b;
a = "some string"
b = a;

a = null;
// b  should be null?
```

as far as i know, there isn't something in java that provide this for you, no operator overloading or preprocessor that can help.

but if you insist I can think of  some *hacks*.

- use C or any other customized preprocessor and define some macro to do this. for example rename all `b` variables with `a` before compilation with java compiler. [check this](https://lyubomyr-shaydariv.github.io/posts/2016-09-06-fun-with-java-and-c-preprocessor/)
- define a singleton object (or just a dummy class) and `a`,`b` keep references to that object, this is actually combination of case 2 and 3;

with static class:

```java
class Global {
    static Object reference;
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Global a = null, b = null;
        a.reference  = "some string value";
        b.reference = null;

        // a.reference is null

    }
}
```

and with singleton class:

```java
class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return Singleton.instance;
    }
    private Singleton() {}

    Object ref;
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Singleton a =  Singleton.getInstance();
        Singleton b = a;

        a.ref = "some string value";
        b.ref = null;

        // a.ref is null
        System.out.println(a.ref);
    }
}
```

(yes I know that isn't same thing that you wanted but java is simple language in syntax level)